# how to fetch data to the Array in the Component from Api in Angular

Tags: angular, angular-services

In the code given below how to values of a service is fetched in the **data** which later we transfer to the array **employee** -
please explain :   **(data => this.employee = data)**

```
  employee: any[];

getEmployees(): Observable<IEmployee[]> {
  return this.http.get<IEmployee[]>(this._url). }

this.empService.getEmployees()
.subscribe(data => this.employee = data);
```

Also , in the code : data => this.employee = data. does data contain all the value and that is transferred to this.employee which is an Array . why we are using FAT ARROW => HERE

Comment: What exactly is your question?

Comment: This is `subscribe` method [documentation](http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/subscribe.html) of `Observable`

Answer (score 0):

Everything is explained in the [Observables Angular documentation](https://angular.io/guide/observables)

With Observables you can make asynchronous action, here you get some datas from something like an API.

Observable objects have a method `subscribe()`, when this method is call the api call is done. This subscribe method take 3 parameters, who are 3 callback functions.

The first one is when the data are resolved in your case this is : `data => this.employee = data`.

The second one is when the observable fail to get some data and the last one is when everything is complete.

Comment: in the code : 
data => this.employee = data.

does data contain all the value and that is transferred to this.employee which is an Array . why we are using FAT ARROW => HERE

Comment: This is just classic arrow function, please just read [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions)